I need to count the number of days between a date and the last day that precipitation was greater than 12
I have a set of data with precipitation totals (Precip) for every day. I collected data at multiple pools. I need to calculate the number of days it has been since the last time it raied >12mm. If it rained over 12mm that day then it get a '0'.
## creates example dataframe
Pool <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
DATE <- as.Date(c("2005-01-01","2005-01-02","2005-01-03","2005-01-04","2005-01-05",
                        "2005-01-06","2005-01-07","2005-01-08","2005-01-09","2005-01-10",
                        "2005-01-01","2005-01-02","2005-01-03","2005-01-04","2005-01-05",
                        "2005-01-06","2005-01-07","2005-01-08","2005-01-09","2005-01-10"))
Precip <- c(0,0,3,18,4,3,13,8,3,0,13,0,3,13,0,3,10,8,13,0))

df <- data.frame(Pool, DATE, Precip)

I need the following dataframe:
   Pool       DATE Precip  Days_since12
1     A 2005-01-01      0     NA
2     A 2005-01-02      0     NA
3     A 2005-01-03      3     NA
4     A 2005-01-04     18     NA
5     A 2005-01-05      4     1
6     A 2005-01-06      3     2
7     A 2005-01-07     13     0
8     A 2005-01-08      8     1
9     A 2005-01-09      3     2
10    A 2005-01-10      0     3
11    B 2005-01-01     13     0
12    B 2005-01-02      0     1
13    B 2005-01-03      3     2
14    B 2005-01-04     13     0
15    B 2005-01-05      0     1
16    B 2005-01-06      3     2
17    B 2005-01-07     10     3
18    B 2005-01-08      8     4
19    B 2005-01-09     13     0
20    B 2005-01-10      0     1
 

I can easily add a column to indicate if the precip was over 12 or not:
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Pool) %>%
  mutate(pre12=ifelse(Precip>12,1,0))

But I am then not sure how to calculate the number of days between the DATE and the previous date when pre12==1

Many of the answers here ignore the value in the date column, instead revert to "counting rows," and therefore require very clean data--which your example provides-- one row per day, no missing values, everything in order.
Using the dates directly provides a more robust approach. Here's one way:
You've got a good start with if_else(), but we can go further. Instead of simply capturing a true/false there, let's record the actual date for any day with precipitation > 12. This is the first step in determining the most recent day with precipitation > 12.
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Pool) %>%
  mutate(latest_12 = if_else(Precip > 12, DATE, NA) %>% as.Date())
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#> # Groups:   Pool [2]
#>    Pool  DATE       Precip latest_12 
#>    <chr> <date>      <dbl> <date>    
#>  1 A     2005-01-01      0 NA        
#>  2 A     2005-01-02      0 NA        
#>  3 A     2005-01-03      3 NA        
#>  4 A     2005-01-04     18 2005-01-04
#>  5 A     2005-01-05      4 NA        
#>  6 A     2005-01-06      3 NA        
#>  7 A     2005-01-07     13 2005-01-07
#>  8 A     2005-01-08      8 NA        
#>  9 A     2005-01-09      3 NA        
#> 10 A     2005-01-10      0 NA        
#> 11 B     2005-01-01     13 2005-01-01
#> 12 B     2005-01-02      0 NA        
#> 13 B     2005-01-03      3 NA        
#> 14 B     2005-01-04     13 2005-01-04
#> 15 B     2005-01-05      0 NA        
#> 16 B     2005-01-06      3 NA        
#> 17 B     2005-01-07     10 NA        
#> 18 B     2005-01-08      8 NA        
#> 19 B     2005-01-09     13 2005-01-09
#> 20 B     2005-01-10      0 NA

Then we can use tidyr::fill() (which is smart enough to stay within groups defined by group_by()) to fill down the last non-missing value into all NAs, to get a column of the latest date with precip > 12 for a given pool. The data needs to be in increasing order here for the fill to do what we want, so don't forget an arrange to cover your backside!
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Pool) %>%
  mutate(latest_12 = if_else(Precip > 12, DATE, NA) %>% as.Date()) %>%
  arrange(Pool, DATE) %>%
  fill(latest_12, .direction = "down")
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#> # Groups:   Pool [2]
#>    Pool  DATE       Precip latest_12 
#>    <chr> <date>      <dbl> <date>    
#>  1 A     2005-01-01      0 NA        
#>  2 A     2005-01-02      0 NA        
#>  3 A     2005-01-03      3 NA        
#>  4 A     2005-01-04     18 2005-01-04
#>  5 A     2005-01-05      4 2005-01-04
#>  6 A     2005-01-06      3 2005-01-04
#>  7 A     2005-01-07     13 2005-01-07
#>  8 A     2005-01-08      8 2005-01-07
#>  9 A     2005-01-09      3 2005-01-07
#> 10 A     2005-01-10      0 2005-01-07
#> 11 B     2005-01-01     13 2005-01-01
#> 12 B     2005-01-02      0 2005-01-01
#> 13 B     2005-01-03      3 2005-01-01
#> 14 B     2005-01-04     13 2005-01-04
#> 15 B     2005-01-05      0 2005-01-04
#> 16 B     2005-01-06      3 2005-01-04
#> 17 B     2005-01-07     10 2005-01-04
#> 18 B     2005-01-08      8 2005-01-04
#> 19 B     2005-01-09     13 2005-01-09
#> 20 B     2005-01-10      0 2005-01-09

Then we can use actual date math on these two columns to compute the elapsed time since the last rain.
df %>%
  group_by(Pool) %>%
  mutate(latest_12 = if_else(Precip > 12, DATE, NA) %>% as.Date()) %>%
  arrange(Pool, DATE) %>%
  fill(latest_12, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(days_since_12 = DATE - latest_12)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 5
#> # Groups:   Pool [2]
#>    Pool  DATE       Precip latest_12  days_since_12
#>    <chr> <date>      <dbl> <date>     <drtn>       
#>  1 A     2005-01-01      0 NA         NA days      
#>  2 A     2005-01-02      0 NA         NA days      
#>  3 A     2005-01-03      3 NA         NA days      
#>  4 A     2005-01-04     18 2005-01-04  0 days      
#>  5 A     2005-01-05      4 2005-01-04  1 days      
#>  6 A     2005-01-06      3 2005-01-04  2 days      
#>  7 A     2005-01-07     13 2005-01-07  0 days      
#>  8 A     2005-01-08      8 2005-01-07  1 days      
#>  9 A     2005-01-09      3 2005-01-07  2 days      
#> 10 A     2005-01-10      0 2005-01-07  3 days      
#> 11 B     2005-01-01     13 2005-01-01  0 days      
#> 12 B     2005-01-02      0 2005-01-01  1 days      
#> 13 B     2005-01-03      3 2005-01-01  2 days      
#> 14 B     2005-01-04     13 2005-01-04  0 days      
#> 15 B     2005-01-05      0 2005-01-04  1 days      
#> 16 B     2005-01-06      3 2005-01-04  2 days      
#> 17 B     2005-01-07     10 2005-01-04  3 days      
#> 18 B     2005-01-08      8 2005-01-04  4 days      
#> 19 B     2005-01-09     13 2005-01-09  0 days      
#> 20 B     2005-01-10      0 2005-01-09  1 days

Because we're doing date math, and we've arranged our data, this approach is robust to missing and out-of-order data.
# change the date of the 5th row from 2005-01-05 to 2005-01-15, 
# creating a missing value and an out-of-order value
df$DATE[5] <- as.Date("2005-01-15") 

df %>%
  group_by(Pool) %>%
  mutate(latest_12 = if_else(Precip > 12, DATE, NA) %>% as.Date()) %>%
  arrange(Pool, DATE) %>%
  fill(latest_12, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(days_since_12 = DATE - latest_12)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 5
#> # Groups:   Pool [2]
#>    Pool  DATE       Precip latest_12  days_since_12
#>    <chr> <date>      <dbl> <date>     <drtn>       
#>  1 A     2005-01-01      0 NA         NA days      
#>  2 A     2005-01-02      0 NA         NA days      
#>  3 A     2005-01-03      3 NA         NA days      
#>  4 A     2005-01-04     18 2005-01-04  0 days      
#>  5 A     2005-01-06      3 2005-01-04  2 days      
#>  6 A     2005-01-07     13 2005-01-07  0 days      
#>  7 A     2005-01-08      8 2005-01-07  1 days      
#>  8 A     2005-01-09      3 2005-01-07  2 days      
#>  9 A     2005-01-10      0 2005-01-07  3 days      
#> 10 A     2005-01-15      4 2005-01-07  8 days      
#> 11 B     2005-01-01     13 2005-01-01  0 days      
#> 12 B     2005-01-02      0 2005-01-01  1 days      
#> 13 B     2005-01-03      3 2005-01-01  2 days      
#> 14 B     2005-01-04     13 2005-01-04  0 days      
#> 15 B     2005-01-05      0 2005-01-04  1 days      
#> 16 B     2005-01-06      3 2005-01-04  2 days      
#> 17 B     2005-01-07     10 2005-01-04  3 days      
#> 18 B     2005-01-08      8 2005-01-04  4 days      
#> 19 B     2005-01-09     13 2005-01-09  0 days      
#> 20 B     2005-01-10      0 2005-01-09  1 days


If there are DATE gaps (using the dates). Since the second group first NA is rather arbitrary (could be 0, too) it needs its own rule.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(Precip > 12)) %>% 
  mutate(Days_since12 = cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(DATE, lag(DATE, default=DATE[1])), "days")), 
         Days_since12 = if_else(grp == 0 | grp == 1 & row_number() == 1, NA, Days_since12), 
         .by = c(grp, Pool)) %>% 
  select(-grp)
   Pool       DATE Precip Days_since12
1     A 2005-01-01      0           NA
2     A 2005-01-02      0           NA
3     A 2005-01-03      3           NA
4     A 2005-01-04     18           NA
5     A 2005-01-05      4            1
6     A 2005-01-06      3            2
7     A 2005-01-07     13            0
8     A 2005-01-08      8            1
9     A 2005-01-09      3            2
10    A 2005-01-10      0            3
11    B 2005-01-01     13            0
12    B 2005-01-02      0            1
13    B 2005-01-03      3            2
14    B 2005-01-04     13            0
15    B 2005-01-05      0            1
16    B 2005-01-06      3            2
17    B 2005-01-07     10            3
18    B 2005-01-08      8            4
19    B 2005-01-09     13            0
20    B 2005-01-10      0            1

Assuming you have data for every day makes the calculation a little lighter, using cumsum and row_number
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(Precip > 12)) %>% 
  mutate(Days_since12 = if_else(grp == 0, NA, row_number() - 1), 
         Days_since12 = if_else(grp == 1 & row_number() == 1, NA, Days_since12),
         .by = c(Pool, grp)) %>% 
  select(-grp)
   Pool       DATE Precip Days_since12
1     A 2005-01-01      0           NA
2     A 2005-01-02      0           NA
3     A 2005-01-03      3           NA
4     A 2005-01-04     18           NA
5     A 2005-01-05      4            1
6     A 2005-01-06      3            2
7     A 2005-01-07     13            0
8     A 2005-01-08      8            1
9     A 2005-01-09      3            2
10    A 2005-01-10      0            3
11    B 2005-01-01     13            0
12    B 2005-01-02      0            1
13    B 2005-01-03      3            2
14    B 2005-01-04     13            0
15    B 2005-01-05      0            1
16    B 2005-01-06      3            2
17    B 2005-01-07     10            3
18    B 2005-01-08      8            4
19    B 2005-01-09     13            0
20    B 2005-01-10      0            1


You could do:
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(group = cumsum(if_else(Precip >= 12, 1, 0))) |> 
  mutate(Days_since12 = if_else(Precip >= 12, 0, as.numeric(DATE - first(DATE))), .by = group) |> 
  mutate(check = all(Precip < 12),
         Days_since12 = if_else(check == TRUE, 0, Days_since12), .by = group) |> 
  select(-check)

which gives:
   Pool       DATE Precip group Days_since12
1     A 2005-01-01      0     0            0
2     A 2005-01-02      0     0            0
3     A 2005-01-03      3     0            0
4     A 2005-01-04     18     1            0
5     A 2005-01-05      4     1            1
6     A 2005-01-06      3     1            2
7     A 2005-01-07     13     2            0
8     A 2005-01-08      8     2            1
9     A 2005-01-09      3     2            2
10    A 2005-01-10      0     2            3
11    B 2005-01-01     13     3            0
12    B 2005-01-02      0     3            1
13    B 2005-01-03      3     3            2
14    B 2005-01-04     13     4            0
15    B 2005-01-05      0     4            1
16    B 2005-01-06      3     4            2
17    B 2005-01-07     10     4            3
18    B 2005-01-08      8     4            4
19    B 2005-01-09     13     5            0
20    B 2005-01-10      0     5            1

Assumption is that your data is sorted by date. Also, I did not take into account the Pool variable, which you also might want to group by.
